# Python 3.6 64 bit configparser works in IDLE but not on open

Tags: python, cmd, config, python-idle

Using Python 3.6 I wrote a config parser script, when I run it in IDLE editor, all works as expected, no problems. However when I use CMD, or just click the file.... Nothing.

When I look into it more, I get told in CMD that 'ConfigParser' is not found... But then why would it work in IDLE?

Hope I have provided enough information, as I have learned on here even the stupidist details make the difference. Thanks agian, this site has saved me a million times

Other issues that may explain problem:

- IDLE is not opening on left click of file "edit with IDLE"

Following Details:

- Windows 7 HP
- 64 bit
- Python 3.6
- PyQt Designer 5.4.1 for Py 3.4 (64 bit) <- Shouldn't be a problem??? 
  (I know Py versions don't match)

Script: (Script is indented on purpose to show up here correctly)

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import configparser

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def clicked_btn(self):
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
user = config.get('section_2', 'user')
self.label.setText(user)
txt = self.lineEdit.text()
#print(txt)
self.pushButton.setText("last text: "+ txt)
config.set('section_4', 'last_text', txt)
f = open('config.ini','w')
config.write(f)
f.close()

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
MainWindow.resize(220, 127)
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
...
 extra code edited out
...
MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
_translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
self.pushButton.setText("Click Me!")
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clicked_btn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you see an error like `ImportError: No module named configparser`, then you're probably running the script in Python 2. Print the value of `sys.version_info` and `sys.prefix` to check the interpreter version and path.

Comment: I know this is a long time later but thank you! I'm an idiot, I have python 2.7 installed and forgot that's the interpreter that was being used when I typed `python` before running a file